# Where can I learn German in Shanghai, China?

Tags: learning

I am Chinese, in Shanghai. I want to learn German. Please give some recommandations like where I can find a school.

I only have time to learn German in weekends.

Comment: As worded now, your question is "too localized", and in my opinion it would have to be closed for this reason. Thus I think you should reword your question and ask for more general advice on how to find a good place to learn German.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [Goethe-Jinchuang Sprachlernzentrum](http://www.goethe-slz.sh.cn/index.asp) .